# Макрос замены фразы целиком. MS Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Исходный текст примерно вида:

> a bc a b

Необходимо заменить `а b` на `a bc` что бы получилось:

> a bc a bc

но при замене получается:

> a bcc a bc

используемый код:

```
With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "a b"
    .MatchWholeWord = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .Replacement.Text = "a bc"
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace := wdReplaceAll
```

как можно сделать поиск для замены "точно как в запросе"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

добавьте `.MatchSuffix = True`

```
With Selection.Find
    .Forward = True
    .ClearFormatting
    .Text = "a b"
    .MatchSuffix = True
    .MatchCase = True
    .Replacement.Text = "a bc"
End With
Selection.Find.Execute Replace := wdReplaceAll
```

---

Второй вариант c помощью [подстановочных знаков](http://artefact.lib.ru/design/text_khozyainov.shtml)

```
.Text = "a b>"
.MatchWildcards = True
```

Comment: `MatchWholeWord = True` работает, но только если искомый текст одно слово. В моем случае, не помогло. (MS Word 2003, MS Word 2010)

Comment: @Nikolay.OAMP обновил ответ. Почему не попробовать сначала заменить через окно замены?

Comment: использование подстановочного знака помогло. "Учитывать суффикс" отсутствует в MS Word 2003, но так же помогает в более новых версиях офиса.